# Javascript Radio Buttons & Name Generator

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I'm trying to create a name generator in Java, and so far I've been able to create some basic functionality using tables. What I'd like is for the script to be able to switch between tables interchangeably perhaps using radio buttons.

i.e. if I wanted to be able to choose between male and female ones rather than it having select some from both. Does anyone know a way to go about this?

```
window.onload = initAll;

function initAll() {
document.getElementById("sillySubmit").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("msgField").innerHTML = getSillyName();
    return false;
}
}

if(document.getElementById('gender_Male').checked) {
}else if(document.getElementById('gender_Female').checked) {

}

function getSillyName() {
var firstName = ["My", "First", "Name"];  

var middleName = ["My", "Second", "Name"]; 

var lastName1 = ["My", "Third", "Name"]; 

var lastName2 = ["My", "Fourth", "Name"];
```

Comment: Where's Java in all this?

Comment: On that note, where's radio in all of this.

Comment: Apologies, edited now. What I'm trying to work out is how to get the radio buttons to read from different lists on selection..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You are using JavaScript and not Java. They are two completly different languages and have nothing to do with each other.

I don't really see your problem. You want `getSillyName` to return different names depending on the gender selected. You have written a check to check what gener is selected but arent' really doing anything with it. Maybe this will help:

```
function getSillyName() {

    //set some gender-independent names
    var firstName = ["My", "First", "Name"],
        middleName = ["My", "Second", "Name"],
        lastName1 = ["My", "Third", "Name"],
        lastName2 = ["My", "Fourth", "Name"];

    if(document.getElementById('gender_Male').checked) {
        // add male only names to the arrays.
    } else if (document.getElementById('gender_Female').checked) {
        //add female only names to the array
    }

    //do your silly magic

}
```

You can add data to an array using the [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method